# App Crashes When Downloaded From App Store But Not When Testing

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, app-store-connect

I have a serious issue which I cannot seem to solve.

Recently I have made an update to an IOS app, and when testing in XCODE as both Ad-Hoc, Debug, and installing via the .IPA on a device the issue cannot be replicated. However when I download the app from the App Store, it crashes.

Does anyone know how this could happen, and any potential solutions? I am getting lots of complaints from users, and not sure what to do?

Could part of the binary upload have got corrupted?

Comment: When it crashes on the device, do you get an error of any kind (you can check crash logs by plugging your device into your Mac, and looking at Organizer)? Otherwise, do you think it might be a provisioning profile issue?

Comment: Hi,I don't think this is the issue. After submission to the App Store, and I download it, the app works, except for 1 area. I cannot replicate this when testing the actual archive from XCODE or ITUNES :(

Comment: Any change in database name, hard coded document directory value (saving previous value and using it) etc

Comment: Install the app in your device from App Store, if it's crashing check the crash log of your device

Comment: Are you using Core Data and changed the entity properties ? Might be good to get a crash reporting library, helps you identify crashes.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you always compiled your app in debug mode. But when sent to App Store you made a release compile. click the arrow in the run button select scheme and chose "release mode" and run your app it will probably crash.

check if you used `NSParameterAssert` as they are not called in release mode

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, I have Xcode6.. Could you explain how I can do it that way. Sorry to be a pain.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot say why your live App Store application is crashing and the debug version is not. Two possible solutions:

**Crash reports:**
To find out why your application crashed, you might want to check if there are any crash reports available on iTunes Connect. Log in on iTunes Connect and click on your application. Scroll down to Crash Reports. You will find out more about why your application is crashing here.

More information about crash reports [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ImprovingCustomersExperience.html) at Apple's own iOS Developer Library.

**Prerelease your app with TestFlight:** For in the future: test your application by uploading it on iTunes Connect and testing it with TestFlight first before submitting the application to the iTunes Store. This will save you a lot of (review) time if you find a error.

Comment: Doesn't work, my app passed TestFlight, Release mode and still crash on AppStore. Reading Crash reports but have no idea which caused the crash

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread but I had the same issue with my App that I released. Meaning it worked fine in testing, but when I released it it would crash. The culprit ended up being the fact that I am using In App Purchases. I have two items that can be "bought" but I had only enabled one of them. In testing it was able to read both of them, but with the release version, it was only pulling the one that was enabled down, creating the crash. The fix was simply enabling the disabled item. I didn't even have to redistribute the app, though I had to wait for it to "percolate" through... Anyway this may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your app is looking for too many IAPs.

I just had this problem and my problem was I had deleted an IAP from the App Store, but didn't remove it from the app code.
For some reason it only crashed when downloaded; I used a promo code to do this before launching my app.

Thanks to Tornado for the inspiration to try this variation.